# Cart page content, display product individual according to quantity

Tags: magento, cart

if i add product with quantity two then in cart contect there is only one product with 2 quantity display. but i want to display separate rows of same product according to quantity.

like cart contect should be as below.

```
product name   Qty  price
ABC             1   $10
ABC             1   $10
```

Finally i got solution. Here is an answer

open this file \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php and search for "_addCatalogProduct" function

and replace

```
$item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
    if (!$item) {

        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $item->setQuote($this);
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
        }
        else {
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $newItem = true;
    }
```

to with commenting code.

```
 // $item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
    //if (!$item) {

        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $item->setQuote($this);
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
        }
        else {
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $newItem = true;
   // }
```

and in \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php

replace

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

to

```
if($params['qty'] == 0 || $params['qty'] == '')
{
  $params['qty'] = 1;
}


$quantity = $params['qty']; 

for($loop=1; $loop<=$quantity; $loop++)
{ 
   $params['qty'] = 1;          
   $cart->addProduct($product, $params);                        
}
```

Comment: this isn't a cool idea to sell same product twice without increasing its quantity in cart..

Comment: yes but i have this kind of requirement as we have to do this. so please give me a solution.

Comment: I dont think this can be done without doing extensive custom coding..

Comment: its possible if we can call multiple time add to cart function according to quantity. and set quantity 1 each time in code.

Comment: No buddy magento will check the stock code and itself increase the quantity to one, one slight possibility (not check though) is by adding different attribute in each products.

Comment: so i am thinking as we allow to add quantity. but when it will go to  display on cart page we do loop multiple times according to quantity with update price for same product. and display same product in separate row according to quantity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44956/discussion-between-amitkumar-solanki-and-skv)

Comment: Why the need for splitting into single line items? What's the scenario?

Comment: because there is a requirement to placing order based on product on whole order. so admin will choose product from orders in adminpanel. do process.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this then you could try creating an observer for the event `sales_order_place_before` and then in your observer you could modify the quote by looping through it and finding multiple qty items, change the qty back to 1 and then add the remainder of items as quote items to the quote object. Not sure if Magento will group them together again during/after the order is placed. You could maybe do the same thing using the event `sales_quote_product_add_after` which might be better as the user will see the individual lines on the cart page, but again, don't know if Magento will group the qty's back together during the checkout process without actually having a go at making it work. If it does, you could maybe try setting the product to be a super product and override the sku so it has a unique identifer tagged on (e.g. SKU100-1, SKU100-2 etc) before you add it to the quote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it is possible to create unique sku for product at run time (on add to cart event observer) so as quato items create another object of same product and comes into another row in cart contect.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

Replace this

```
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

with that on line 130 default theme /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

```
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php $qty = $_item->getQty() ?>
        <?php for($i=0; $i < $qty; $i++) : ?>
            <?php $_item->setQty(1); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item); ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: NOTE: I set item qty without save or edit quote item, if you need only to render that, i suggest you to edit also cart/render/ files to remove input and change qty for all items.

Comment: it works so thanks for your reply  but its on display level not a functional level. so whereever cart is display in checkout process or in adminpanel. i have to do same there. that's why i want to do it as functional level.

Comment: I think there is a logic in \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php in addProductAdvanced() function on line number 965.

Comment: or there is another logic in \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item.php in setProduct() function in line number 379.